# Maps are truncated in openlayers' map save feature

Tags: openlayers

Hello I am making a function to save a map using openlayers.

I saw and implemented the example here, but there is an error.
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/export-map.html

There is no error message,
The url(var link) is generated with the map clipped.

I have no idea why this cropped image is obtained.

Source code and images are attached. 
Anyone who knows in detail, I would appreciate your help.

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    layers: [
      new ol.layer.Tile({
        source: new ol.source.OSM()
      })
    ],
    view: new ol.View({
        projection: 'EPSG:3857',
        center: ol.proj.transform([128.5840806,35.7612105], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
        zoom: 11,
        minZoom: 6,
        maxZoom: 18
    }),
  });



function SaveMapImage() {
map.once('postcompose', function(){
    var mapCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var size = map.getSize();
    mapCanvas.width = size[0];
    mapCanvas.height = size[1];

    var mapContext = mapCanvas.getContext('2d');

    Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.querySelectorAll('.ol-layer canvas'), function(canvas){
        if(canvas.width == size[0] && canvas.height == size[1])
        {
            var opacity = canvas.parentNode.style.opacity;

            mapContext.globalAlpah = opacity === '' ? 1 : Number(opacity);
            var transform = canvas.style.transform;

            var matrix = transform.match(/^matrix\(([^\(]*)\)$/)[1].split(',').map(Number);

            CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.setTransform.apply(mapContext, matrix);

            mapContext.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
        }
    });

    var link = mapCanvas.toDataURL();
    console.log(link.toString());

});
map.renderSync();
```

}

- original map
  [image]
- function error map
  [image]

Comment: It might be a browser limit on memory or canvas.  Have you tried different device or browser?

Comment: As a result of testing, the mapCanvas.toDataURL displayed in the log is cut when copied and pasted into Chrome browser.  But the map save works just fine. thank you